# Sphinx get millions of results

Tags: mysql, performance, sphinx

I use **MySQL** + **Sphinx** to store many millions rows of data. We have website to view all information from our database.

For example, movie titles (**100,000,000** rows). I need to view ALL of them on our website, 100 titles per page. Also, i need view them sorted by actors popularity.

For the first 10 pages all works great. But after that i reached [max_matches](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-max-matches.html) limit. Increasing this limit will force sphinx to use more CPU/RAM.

Also, i can't even set max_matches to **20,000,000**.

> WARNING: max_matches=20000000 out of bounds; using default 1000

I can use MySQL to perform queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM titles WHERE tid >= $start AND tid <= $end
```

to use **tid** index. But i can't sort it by **tid**. I need to sort my titles by info from other tables.

What is the best way to get access to many millions of rows, sorted and do it quick. Please help.

**UPDATE**: from sphinx source: **/src/searchd.cpp**

```
if ( iMax<0 || iMax>10000000 )
{
    sphWarning ( "max_matches=%d out of bounds; using default 1000", iMax );
} else
{
    g_iMaxMatches = iMax;
}
```

Is **10000000** is a limit ? How can i get offset more than that ?

Comment: this is not recommended, u can just paginate it, can't?

Comment: what do you mean ? the problem is, that i can't paginate it...

Comment: what you can do is break the millions rows into smaller results set, and each time, you just fetch 1000 records, i mean, a loop

Comment: Do you really need an offset of 10 millions ?  even if you put 1000 per page , that's 10K pages - I doubt anyone will go as far . Note that max_matches is for returned results , it doesn't mean it will search just in 10 millions. For example, Google doesn't let you go beyond 1000 offset :)

Comment: yes i need thousands of pages. i yes need indeed. that the task i have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your sort order is based on an attribute (actors popularity) - rather than sphinxes computed weight - then can just use cursors instead.

Because can filter by this attribute.

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/search.html?q=cursors&f=1

I do have to wonder tho, if you REALLY need it. At 100 items per page, a max_matches of 1M, means 10,000 pages of results. Do your visitors really go though reading 10,000 pages of results?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIMIT` ([select api](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/sphinxql-select.html)) to retrieve a specific page.

Anything you want to order by needs to be included in the index, you cannot use joins here.

Comment: i still have offset limits: ERROR 1064 (42000): query 0 error: offset out of bounds (offset=1000000, max_matches=1000)